# toggle visibility of kml folders in GE plugin

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have searched high and low for just a snippet of java script code showing this, but all I'm trying to figure out is how to toggle parts of a KML, mainly folders, using check-boxes or similar.  Currently the KML is loaded to the plugin using a networklink.

All of the examples I find want you to have separate kml files for everything, but given the sheer number of assets I'm dealing with that wouldn't be feasible.  I know this is possible.  All I'm looking for is just that one example of "click this, then this "folder" appears".

Any help is greatly appreciated!